# Displaying Metabox value (custom post type taxonomy)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, metabox, post-meta, meta-query

I have been stuck on this for days, reading articles and articles and nothing works. I am trying to display the value of my metabox on a template page.

I successfully added the metabox, and I see the select box in my page admin, it also seems to be saving fine.

I just can't seem to get the selected category in the metabox to echo on the template page.

Everywhere I have read said to use the following which isn't working for me.

```
<?php 
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sm_taxonomy', true );
?>
```

The rest of my code is below

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'sm_register_meta_boxes' );

function sm_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes )
{


/**
 * Prefix of meta keys (optional)
 * Use underscore (_) at the beginning to make keys hidden
 * Alt.: You also can make prefix empty to disable it
 */
// Better has an underscore as last sign
$prefix = 'sm_';

$meta_boxes = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'my-meta-box-2',
'title' => 'Portfolio Category',
'pages' => array('page', ''), // custom post type
'show_on' => array( 'key' => 'page-template', 'value' => 'grid-gallery.php' ),
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
    array(
            'name'    => __( 'Choose a category', 'rwmb' ),
            'id'      => "{$prefix}taxonomy",
            'type'    => 'taxonomy',
            'options' => array(
                // Taxonomy name
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                // How to show taxonomy: 'checkbox_list' (default) or 'checkbox_tree', 'select_tree', select_advanced or 'select'. Optional
                'type' => 'select',
                // Additional arguments for get_terms() function. Optional
                'args' => array()
            ),
        ),
)
);
return $meta_boxes;

foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
$my_box = new My_meta_box($meta_box);
}

add_action('save_post', 'save');

}
```

and..

```
class My_meta_box {

protected $_meta_box;

// create meta box based on given data
function __construct($meta_box) {
    $this->_meta_box = $meta_box;
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add'));

    add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'save'));
}

/// Add meta box for multiple post types
function add() {
    foreach ($this->_meta_box['pages'] as $page) {
        add_meta_box($this->_meta_box['id'], $this->_meta_box['title'], array(&$this, 'show'), $page, $this->_meta_box['context'], $this->_meta_box['priority']);
    }
}

// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function show() {
    global $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="',     wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($this->_meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'select':
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
                break;
            case 'radio':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
                }
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
                break;
        }
        echo     '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

// Save data from meta box
function save($post_id) {
    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($this->_meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump( get_post_meta( $post->ID ) )` returns?

Comment: I'd like to see your entire page template. It's possible that `$post` is either not yet set (at the time that you're trying to access it) or something else overwrites its value (like a custom `WP_Query` running before your code and populating the global `$post` object, but not resetting it back to the original page object when it finishes).

Comment: Are you using [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) plugin? If yes, the plugin has a helper function rwmb_meta to retrieve the terms.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

- For `single` template

`global $post;`
`echo get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'sm_taxonomy', true );`

OR

- For `archive` template

`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`
`echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'sm_taxonomy', true );`
`endif;`

Answer (score 0):

display by ID: if  'id' => 'my-meta-box-2', then 
ID, 'my-meta-box-2', true );
?>
if you are using the rwmb plugin view the resource to echo the plugin correctly.

Comment: Please format your code and add some explanation of your answer.